# ¿Por qué me salta error en los corchetes si están bien puestos y los puntos y coma también están bien puestos?

Tags: java, archivo

La siguiente clase no me deja compilar, me salta error de corchetes, primero en la línea 37 y después en el último corchete, si elimino el procedimiento void el error me pasa al punto y coma del bufferreader anterior.****

**Syntax error on token "}", { expected after this tokenJava(1610612967)**

He revisado los corchetes si cierran bien los bloques de códigos y sí las instrucciones tienen los punto y coma bien puesto pero no veo nada raro sera que estoy cansado.

Si alguien puede ver el error que yo no veo estaría genial.

```
// Paquete (carpeta) donde van a estar mis clases.
package FicherosTexto;

// Importamos los paquetes necesarios para poder instanciar los objetos y sus métodos.
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

// Incluye la lectura de los archivos de los clientes y los métodos referentes a estos datos.
public class DatosCliente {

    // Atributos de la clase según la toma de requisitos.
    /*
    private String id;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellidos;
    private String telefono;
    private String correo;
    */
    
    // Creamos las listas que van a almacenar los teléfonos, los correos y la cantidad de clientes que llegue a tener el documento.
    ArrayList <String> telefonos = new ArrayList <String> ();
    ArrayList <String> correos = new ArrayList <String> ();
    ArrayList <String> clientes = new ArrayList <String> ();

    // Objetos sin inicializar.
    // Para importar un archivo.
    File archivo = null;

    // Para poder leer datos del archivo.
    FileReader fr = null;

    // Incluye métodos para trabajar con los archivos.
    BufferedReader br = null;

    public void total () {
        System.out.println(clientes);
    }

    // Intentar como primera opción esto.
    try {

        /*  - Apertura del fichero y creación de BufferedReader.
         *  - Para poder hacer una lectura cómoda (disponer del metodo readLine()).
         *  - ¡Ojo con la ruta, esto es solo un ejemplo!.
         */ 
        archivo = new File ("C:/Users/CristoPWin11/Desktop/Cristo_UT6_FicherosTexto/datos.txt");

        // ¡El archivo debe existir con anterioridad!.
        fr = new FileReader (archivo);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        // Lectura del fichero.
        String linea;
        String [] parts = linea.split(",");

        while ((linea=br.readLine())!=null) {
            clientes.add(linea);
        }
    }
 
    // En caso de error. 
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    /*  
     *  - En el finally cerramos el fichero.
     *  - Para asegurarnos que se cierra tanto si todo va bien como si salta una excepcion.
     */ 
    finally {

        try {
            if( null != fr )
            fr.close();
        }

        catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Todo el bloque try{ ...} catch está fuera de un método o bloque static, es normal que de error

Comment: Gracias Máquina.

Answer (score 1):

La funcion public void total () solo hace un System.out. Tu problema esta en que tienes código fuera de una función, el try catch finally no estan dentro de ninguna funcion y por eso te salta el error de que no espera un cocrchete de cerrar en la funcion public void total (), si no que continue el try catch

```
public void total () {
    System.out.println(clientes);


    // Intentar como primera opción esto.
    try {

        /*  - Apertura del fichero y creación de BufferedReader.
        *  - Para poder hacer una lectura cómoda (disponer del metodo readLine()).
        *  - ¡Ojo con la ruta, esto es solo un ejemplo!.
        */ 
        archivo = new File ("C:/Users/CristoPWin11/Desktop/Cristo_UT6_FicherosTexto/datos.txt");

        // ¡El archivo debe existir con anterioridad!.
        fr = new FileReader (archivo);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        // Lectura del fichero.
        String linea;
        String [] parts = linea.split(",");

        while ((linea=br.readLine())!=null) {
            clientes.add(linea);
        }
    }

    // En caso de error. 
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    /*  
    *  - En el finally cerramos el fichero.
    *  - Para asegurarnos que se cierra tanto si todo va bien como si salta una excepcion.
    */ 
    finally {

        try {
            if( null != fr )
            fr.close();
        }

        catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}